# Instantiating a "native" QML type dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to pick between different types of sub-components dynamically (during instantiation)?

For example, some pseudocode (using Qt 5.9):

```
 //MyComp.qml
 import QtQuick 2.9
 import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3          

 Item {
   property bool useLayout: true

   //Here I want to allow the user to choose
   //whether a ColumnLayout or Column is used 
   //(e.g., by means of the useLayout property)
   ColumnLayout { //Or Column
     ...
   }
 ...
 }
```

---

```
 //main.qml
 import QtQuick 2.9
 import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
 import QtQuick.Controls 2.9

 ApplicationWindow {
 width: 640
 height: 480
 ...
  MyComp {
    id: a
    useLayout: false
    ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you try to achieve by that since there are variouse ways to do that and the correct choice depends on your use case. Some might be simple (just use a `Loader`) and some might be quite complicated.

Comment: I use this MyComp component originally with a ColumnLayout inside, it works fine except for a subcomponent placed into that ColumnLayout: a custom "native" Text type with WordWrap & ElideRight enabled, one after another. So, when this Text has multiple lines, text (property) appears on top of the next Text. I noticed that when using ColumnLayout, Text.contentHeight always returns the value of a single line even for multi-line text adjusted to word wrapping. lineNumber property also returns 1. But, if there is a '\n', both property return correct values. Column, on the other hand, works fine.

Comment: Could you post a code that illustrates the problem you just described in your comment?

Comment: I'm stuck using the custom component other developer created, which contains a `Text`. The documentation says that contentHeight and lineCount should return those expected values. I believe there might be a bug with `ColumnLayout`. Anyway, I'll try with a `Label` too and make a suggestion if that works. The `Text`s inside the `ColumnLayout` is placed statically but the `text` is read at runtime from a local database.

Comment: I solved that by setting a `Layout.preferredHeight` property. For anyone with the same issue, if the contained `Text` is multi-line due to word wrapping in a `ColumnLayout` (with `Column` it works fine), I had to set that property accordingly, otherwise the alignment would be off. I couldn't find any reference to this in the original documentation, so it's a bit of trial and error. Since I hadn't mentioned about that issue in the original question, I'll accept @RickPat's as the answer, as his solution is not exactly what was asked but would work in this case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want, without a lot of javascript. The cleanest way to do  this, that I can think  of would be the following.
You could make the ColumnLayout invisible and set the Column as the parent of its children with something like this:

```
//MyComp.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Item {
    property bool useLayout: true


    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout

        visible: useLayout

        Component.onCompleted: {
            if (!useLayout) {
                butt1.parent = column;
                butt2.parent = column;
                butt3.parent = column;
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: butt1
            text: "butt 1"
        }
        Button {
            id: butt2
            text: "butt 2"
        }
        Button {
            id: butt3
            text: "butt 3"
        }
    }
    Column {
        id: column

        visible: !useLayout
    }
}
```